# Simple php birthday checker

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write a php script to check if today's date is the user's birthday that they have entered through an html form.  It doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Birthday Check</title>
</head> 
<body background="birthday.jpg">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['birthDate'])){
  $bDay = $_POST["birthDate"];
  $time = strtotime($bDay);
  if(date('m/d') == date('m/d', $time)) {
    echo "Happy Birthday!";
  }
}
?>

<center><form name="birthdayCheck" method="POST" action="BirthdayCheck.php">

<h1><i><font color="yellow"> Please enter your birth date</font></i></h1>
<br>
            <input type="date" name="birthDate"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"><br>
</form></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do the values come out as? `var_dump(date('m/d'));` and `var_dump(date('m/d', $time));`. If different check the `$time`, then `$bDay`. Also `type="date"` doesn't function the same in all browsers.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, tested in Firefox and Chrome, PHP 7.

Comment: My echo statements are not working, the values for var_dumps are correct for each variable.  I am using chrome